# One hot from strings - getting the index in list of uniques

Tags: python, numpy, one-hot-encoding

**Is there a convenient way of extracting indices from an array of strings?** I'm looking to do a simple one-hot encoding with NumPy. I have a way of doing the encoding itself, but first I would need a list of indices to encode.

Getting the sorted unique elements is straightforward.

```
>>> vals = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a'])
>>> uniq = np.unique(vals)
array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
```

Then the conversion would take place. First I thought about using `list.index` using basic Python lists, but that involves converting the list from `ndarray` to `list` and back. And I imagine there is a better solution.

What I came up with was:

```
idx = [np.where(uniq == v) for v in vals]
```

but this produces an array of nd-arrays.

And for the expected output naturally:

```
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: So, what is your expected output? One hot or categorical encodings? Your title and question say different things.

Comment: If it's the encodings, then add a `return_inverse=True` arg: `u, i = np.unique(vals, return_inverse=True)`

Comment: Depending on why you need this, you might also look into sklearn's [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `return_inverse=True`:

```
vals = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a'])
u, indices = np.unique(vals, return_inverse=True)

print(u)  # ['a' 'b' 'c']
print(indices)  # [0 1 2 1 0]
```

Comment: Thanks! Surprisingly easy, at first reading the docs I didn't quite get the inverse.